# How can I get a tree view for content types out of the metadata navigation hierarchy in a document library?

Tags: document-library, content-type, navigation

I have a hierarchy of content types that's currently two levels deep, and could go to three. These are for legal documents and may ultimately be used as templates in Word... which is why I opted to go for content types vs managed metadata. I have a total of about 30 content types.

Here's my question. In my document library, how can I enable the out-of-box metadata navigation hierarchy to display something other than a flat list? It completely flattens my content types, so that research documents get mixed in with litigation documents (which are separate branches on the tree). I know I could get the effect I want if I switched to managed metadata, but then I'd lose the ability to template.

Is there a way to display the content type hierarchy, in a tree view, as metadata navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replicate the content type hierarchy as a term set and add a managed metadata column to each of the content types. Set each content type's MM field to default to the exact same name of the content type. Now content type and MM field match and you can use the MM field for metadata navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **SharePoint 2007 Features** project on Codeplex.  It includes a hierarchical content type viewer feature:
http://features.codeplex.com

It's the **Content Type Hierarchy** feature in the **Developer-Oriented Features** section.